# How to add padding-top for Monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

How can I add padding between the first line of code and top border of Monaco editor?

I have this:

[image]

But I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding a padding to monaco editor area (lines content)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431915/adding-a-padding-to-monaco-editor-area-lines-content)

Comment: Add `padding: { top: 25 }` as one of your `monaco` options

Comment: Note to readers: `padding` was not introduced until [`v0.21.0`](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0210-21092020)

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but this initial option is available (monaco v0.41.0):

```
const options = {
    padding: {
        top: 10
    }
    // more options...
}
monaco.editor.create(anElement, options);
```

See: [IEditorPaddingOptions](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/editor.IEditorPaddingOptions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.monaco-editor {
 padding-top: 15px;
}
```

It worked for me

Comment: Interesting that this got downvoted but the comment from @locomain links to a similar answer...

I can confirm this works :)

Comment: This did not work for me; if you have the height set and also do the above, the child `overflow-guard` stays its same height but is just pushed down `15px`.

Comment: this will disable the popups when you hover over the code.

Comment: This did not work for me as the background of the editor was also shifted from the padding, not just the text content. Using the padding of the editor options worked well.

Comment: This caused an infinite loop for us. Monaco tried to keep resizing the editor, seems like this will mess with their calculations.